# System cannot find path specified

Tags: java, eclipse, file, maven

I'm reading information from a (maven) generated file located at `target/[projectname]/WEB-INF/classes/`. Eclipse does not show me the path, however, I cannot create a new folder named `classes` in `WEB-INF` (because there is already an existing one).

I can find the folder and the file via the command line, however, I cannot create a `FileInputStream` for the file.

However, I get access to other files located in `target`, e.g., `target/maven-archiver/pom.properties`, which is already generated during each build. The only difference is that I can see the file in Eclipse.

The project is a GWT one and built with maven. I don't see any reason why Java cannot find the path.

The file I'm accessing is `version.properties`. I can see it in the explorer (the project name is blacked out):

[image: File Location]

I try to open the file via

```
private static final String PATH = "target/[projectname]/WEB_INF/classes/version.properties";

public static String getVersion() {
    String version;
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    File resource = new File(PATH);
    try {
        prop.load(new FileInputStream(resource));
        version = prop.getProperty("build.time");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        version = "01.01.2016 00:00";
    }
    return version;
}
```

The exception I get is

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: target\[projectname]\WEB_INF\classes\version.properties (Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at [projectname].utils.VersionUtils.getBuildTime(VersionUtils.java:31)
[...]
```

Comment: Why do you need to access the target directory from your code?

Comment: @Ferrybig Because the file is automatically generated and thus, only available with the generated output at this place (contains maven properties specified with `${propertyName}`).

Comment: @LordAnomander you may have more success using getClass().getResource("\version.properties"), as your code seems to be compiled to some kind of container, but I am not sure about the format

Comment: @user2004685 - do you think the path `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/version.properties` is valid during runtime in a production environment? ;-)

Comment: @Ulrich If the properties file is kept on classpath then just `new ClassPathResource("version.properties")` should work! :)

Comment: @user2004685 - `ClassPathResource("version.properties")` is correct if `version.properties` is located in the same package as the class performing `new ClassPathResource()` . Use `/version.properties` if it belongs to rrot. But `src/main/webapp`  isn't part of the classpath.

Comment: @Ulrich Yes. I agree. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it completely wrong.

`version.properties` is a resource of your application located inside `src/main/resources`. When you have your final WAR, this file will be on the classpath of your application. This is because Maven will place this resource inside the folder `WEB-INF/classes` of your WAR. You do not access this file with the path `target/...` or `src/main/...`. This is an Eclipse / Maven consideration. Once you have your final WAR, `target` doesn't even exist anymore.

Secondly, you can not access a resource as a `File` object. You must get an `InputStream` of the resource instead.

Combining all of this, you should have:

```
prop.load(VersionUtils.class.getResourceAsStream("/version.properties"));‌​
```

The path given to `getResourceAsStream` is a path that is either relative to the location of the current class, or absolute to the classpath. In this case, the resource is at the root of the classpath so we just use `"/version.properties"`.